# How to send a variable from JS to my Laravel Controller

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

I'm sorry. I have researched for several hours, several and I still do not reach success with this.

Let me explain:

I'm on the route `/events/1`, so I'm already inside the details of the event.

When I select a date (that is why it is the variable "day_id") it makes a query. But each event has different days, that is why I need to pass the event ID also to make the query.

```
$event_id = "Dynamic Value";
$data = Hour::where('selected_date', $day_id)->where('event_id', $event_id)->get();
```

I don't know if I explain myself well, what I need to do is also that the ID is dynamic, like the `day_id`.

I've been trying for more than 5 days in many ways.

I'm trying to get the ID of my "Event" via JavaScript and I want to send it as a variable to the controller but I have not been able to yet. Could anyone help me, please?

```
@section('scripts')
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $(document).on('change', '#day', function(){
         var day_id=$(this).val();
         var event_id = $('#event_id').val();
         // console.log(day_id);
         // console.log(event_id);

         $.get('/hour?day_id=' + day_id, function(data){
            $('#hours').empty();
            $('#hours').append('<option value="0" disable selected="true"> Selecciona la hora</option>');

               for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                  currentDay = data[i].hour; 
                  console.log(currentDay);
                  $('#hours').append('<option value="'+ data[i].hour +'">'+ data[i].hour +'</option>');
               }
         })
      });
   });
</script>
@endsection
```

With this code I'm getting the value of the date, but now I need to show the time depending on the ID of the event. That's why I need to pass the variable `event_id` to the controller method. I'm using `var event_id = $('#event_id').val();`

This is the code in the Controller:

```
   {
      $day_id = Input::get('day_id');
      $event_id = '2'; //I need this to be dynamic
      $data = Hour::where('selected_date', $day_id)->where('event_id', $event_id)->get();

      return response()->json($data);
   }
```

Web.php

`Route::get('/hour', 'Events\EventController@getHours')->name('ajax.hour');`

Once again, I'm sorry. I have researched for several hours, several and I still do not reach success with this.

What I need is to know how to how to pass `event_id` variable to laravel controller. Thanks!

Comment: You're already passing day_id, why don't you pass event_id the same way?

Comment: I try, but I really don't succeed.

Comment: Well, what did you add?  The fact that day_id is already passed makes me think you're attempting to modify someone else's code that you don't understand.  Take the time to research each line of code that you don't understand because modifying someone else's code you don't understand is a great way to break things, cause bad side effects, or introduce security holes.

Comment: It's not someone else's code. I've been trying to get the ID for several days. For that there is this community, to seek help when you cann't. Am I doing wrong if I ask the community?

I need help with this because I feel like it gets out of hand.

Comment: It's not wrong, but you didn't really say what you tried, you just posted a code block with no explanation.  It gives the impression you didn't research the problem thoroughly and are just looking for someone else to write the code for you.  Tell us what you tried and why you expect that to work.

Comment: I'm so sorry for giving that bad impression. I updated my question again. It's probably better now. I also clarified that I've been investigating for several days without success. Thank you and sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, yes, you're getting the event ID here:

```
var event_id = $('#event_id').val();
```

But you're not doing anything with that variable.  If you never use a variable you've assigned, that's a major indication that you have a problem in your code.  Some programming languages will even refuse to compile because of it.

Pass the event ID in the query string of your GET request, just like you're doing with day ID:

```
$.get('/hour?day_id=' + day_id + '&event_id=' + event_id, function(data){
```

Then retrieve it the same way from the Input facade:

```
$event_id = Input::get('event_id');
```